# "secure access corridor disengaged" - meaning?

Tags: meaning-in-context

i heard this announcement somewhere in a video game(half life) where freeman runs somewhere.

what does it mean?

1. that the corridor is now open?
2. that the secure access in the corridor is not secure anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Disengaged' means to not be connected no longer, become separate to what it was before. So, in that sentence, it means the secure access corridor is no longer accessible / usable or cannot be entered.